# Excel: How to list row heads for all places multiple values occur in a table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel file that lists Product Names in the left column, and Components of those products in several columns next to each Product. Each component can be used in multiple products. What I want to do is create a list of Components that shows which Products they are used in. See example below where I give an example of what I have and what I want to create. I've read a bunch of posts about a baffling collection of array formulas, etc., but can't figure out how to adapt any of those to my needs. Using Microsoft 365 version of Excel.

[Example showing sample data and desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeKqK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*An array (CSE) formula wrapped with IFERROR solves the isuue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- An array (CSE) Formula in cell G48:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$48:$A$53, SMALL(IF($F48=$B$48:$D$53, ROW($A$48:$A$53)-47,""), COLUMN()-6)),"")}
  ```

**N.B.**

- -47 & -6 are editable values.
- Where 47 is Row number has Headers (A47:D47).
- 6 is Column position of Col F.
- Since formula starts from Column 7 (G48).

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: Wonderful! This worked great! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help you @NinjaDoug,,, keep asking ☺